# text wraps in html when I dont want it to, but when I use the no wrap tag, it extends along the page.

Tags: html, resize

.....which makes sense. 
However, is there a way to limit the amount of space that a paragraph for example takes up? Right now, if someone resizes the page, the text wraps and the elements overlap each other, and I understand that it is just working as designed.

I was able to get a no-wrap successful set up using a table as a whole page layout, but that just caused other issues.

How can I get it so that the text doesnt move without using the no-wrap option. Should I put the p tag in it's own div? or span?

I'm sorry, this may be simple, but I cannot find a good answer. If I wrap, they overlap. If I no-wrap, it...well...no-wraps, but all I am looking for is for it to stay within the parameters of the page, and not resize when the page resizes. Ideas? Feel free to shake your head - just looking for some relief from the confusion haha

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i fully understand the question, but you could try selecting the surrounding div and applying the following css.

```
selector{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Set the width to the size you want, before the wrap

Comment: I attempted that, but no such luck. I placed the p tags within a div tag and replaced the selector word above with my div class, and at first nothing happened. Then, I realized I should try the whitespace no wrap and it reverted back to the same issue. it ignore my width and did what it was told and didnt wrap. strange.

Comment: I figured it out, but thank you. I set the position to absolute and the width to whatever I needed it to be, and now the paragraph stays within those limits and also does not get smaller when the browser gets smaller.